# Why does this DNS lookup fail for me but work for others?

Tags: domain-name-system

### Day One

I have to hide the actual host names, so I'm *hoping* there is still enough information to answer this question...

I'm trying to resolve a certain host name (let's pretend it's `www.example.com`, but this is **not** the actual host name).  A simple `dig` request works, but when I try to do a series of `dig` starting from a root nameserver, I hit a dead-end.  Here's an example:

```
# Starting with arbitrarily-chosen root nameserver
$ dig @198.41.0.4 www.example.com
(returns the usual list of TLD .com nameservers)

# Using a.gtld-servers.net
$ dig @192.5.6.30 www.example.com
(returns a list of 5 example.com authorities)
```

At this point, I tried each of the 5 `example.com`authorities.  *Three* of them fail with status `SERVFAIL`, and the remaining two time out.  Here's a `SERVFAIL` example:

```
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 33577
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.example.com.       IN  A

;; Query time: 74 msec
;; SERVER: <intentionally removed>
;; WHEN: Tue Mar  8 10:10:33 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 37
```

I tried this multiple times, from my own machine at home and from a remote machine in our co-lo, and both machines consistently get the same results.

However,

- As I mentioned above, `dig www.example.com` (without specifying an `@server`) works fine.
- This [DNS trace utility](http://www.simpledns.com/lookup-dg.aspx) is able to resolve the host name, and it clearly shows that it's using one of the name servers that times out for me!

Can anybody help me figure out what's going on?

**EDIT 1:** In case it helps, what *should* happen is that this host name should ultimately resolve to a CNAME record pointing to `www.example.com.edgesuite.net`, which should in turn resolve to *another* CNAME record pointing to an Akamai edge server.

**EDIT 2:** Per Joris's recommendation, I ran `dig +trace www.example.com`, and it actually failed to find a result.  It gets to the same list of `example.com` authorities that I found before, and stops there.

Caching seems like a very likely culprit (and I did think of this earlier), but the weird part is that the actual host name isn't that popular.  Would it be cached on two different ISP local nameservers if I'm the first person to request it? :-)

---

### Day Two

OK, I've discovered a few things:

1. The two `example.com` authorities that I *thought* were timing out (as opposed to the other three, that were returning `SERVFAIL`) are not actually timing out.  They just require a much *longer* timeout.  If I use `dig +time=10`, for example, then I do eventually get back a result.
2. I've tried this from several servers around the U.S., and the story is the same -- using `dig www.example.com` returns a result very quickly, but `dig @ns1.example.com` (or `@ns2.example.com`) requires using a large timeout parameter.

**So my new questions are:**

1. Could the result really be cached on a variety of proxying DNS servers, even though it's not a commonly-used host name?  The TTL is 54,000 (or 15 hours, if I understand correctly).
2. If not, then is it possible that `ns1.example.com` is somehow configured to return a result more quickly to proxying DNS servers than to my own `dig` queries (some kind of white list)?  Or is that just crazy talk?

Comment: This is a publicly registered domain name, right? So why keep the name secret? We're going to be very limited in helping you without the actual name.

Comment: @joeqwerty That what I was afraid of :-(.  I understand your reaction, but this is on behalf of a customer whose name I am not at liberty to disclose. The customer's identity will be obvious if I include the host name.  I'm _hoping_ someone can help me figure this out without the specifics, but I'm aware of the realities :-(.

Answer (score 3):

[Don't obscure your DNS data when asking for help with DNS problems](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dont-obscure-your-dns-data.html).  It's pointless and silly, and this is a classic example of how it has served to obscure the actual problem that you have.

There are two major possibilities here:

- **You have intermittent connectivity to the content DNS servers.**  A common cause of such problems is an IP traffic routing problem, or a simple case of there being too many hops between you and them.  Find out the IP addresses of the 5 content DNS servers in question, and use `traceroute` or some such to determine that you really do have IP connectivity to them all.  Test UDP/IP connectivity to port 53, specifically, if your tool is capable of it.
- **The answer was provided in one of the paths that you didn't take when doing things manually, and that your resolving proxy DNS server only takes sometimes.**  The unfortunate truth about DNS query resolution is that there are a lot more paths that it can take down the tree of the DNS namespace than one might think from the superficial explanations of the process that exist.  It's possible, for example, that the first `CNAME` resource record set (which you cannot obtain) was served up, and then cached by your [resolving proxy DNS server](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-server-roles.html#ResolvingProxy), when mapping the names of some of the higher level content DNS servers to addresses.  Given that your resolving proxy DNS server sometimes works, you can find out how it discovered the answer by looking at its query/response logs.  (Some DNS server softwares have to have this logging explicitly turned on.  Some have it on by default.  How to do it for your particular software, which you haven't stated, is the domain of a separate question.)

Note that the only caching that occurrs here is local, on *your* resolving proxy DNS server.  The content DNS servers that you are querying don't cache.  (Or, more strictly speaking, if they do cache they cache the back-end databases that they are working from, in ways that have little to nothing to do with resource record TTLs, and that aren't publicly visible through the DNS protocol.)

There are a couple of minor and fairly unlikely possibilities as well, including daft firewalls at your site rewriting DNS traffic on the fly as it passes through them.  But since you've not provided proper data, there's little more to narrow down and rule-out the possibilities that you can obtain from random passers-by out on Internet.

Comment: I appreciate your position, but it's simply not possible to provide the host name.  However, +1 for useful information.

Comment: I've added some more information that might be helpful (see "Day Two" above).  If you have any thoughts, it would be great to get your input :-).

Comment: I really liked that first link! +1

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate any chance of faulty queries, could you try dig +trace example.com? It will follow the chain for you. If that succeeds, (it will only try one of the authorities at each level), you have at least one working trail.

If multiple tries all fail, there is something broken. Chances are you're seeing cached answers with the "normal" request; expect the breakage to surface as soon as the TTL expires.

Comment: Hi Joris.  Caching had definitely occurred to me.  I'll add the +trace results to my question.

Comment: Then it would seem your DNS setup is faulty, somewhere near the example.com authorities.

Answer (score 0):

> At this point, I tried each of the 5
>   foo.com authorities.

I get two authorities:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
foo.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns.okdirect.com.
foo.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns2.okdirect.com.
```

Both resolve `www.foo.com` correctly.

Comment: Hi embobo.  As I mentioned, this is not the actual host name I am using.  It was just an example since I can't share the real one.

Comment: I realized this wasn't as clear as it could have been :-).  I edited the question, hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the number of authorized name servers for your domain ? 
At the level that you are querying, these are handled at the registrar level.
If you saw 5 before and now you see 2, I'd have to guess you made a change to your authorized name server entries ?

Next time try a simple telnet to port 53 of the authorized name servers

Comment: The queries and responses are almost certainly using UDP/IP, not TCP/IP.  `telnet` is overrated and often inappropriate as a diagnostic tool, especially in this case.  TELNET, the protocol that it speaks, is not actually a bare bones TCP/IP raw data protocol.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an ACL issue on the name servers. The best practice is to separate resolvers and authoritative servers. The domain sounds to have 2x authoritative servers and three caching resolvers that have restrictive acls preventing your query for the domain.  Your "however" case works due to the request being a query and not asking for recursion.

In bind you should have the following three options specified or the default will be applied, which has changed with bind versions.

allow-recursion { none; };
allow-query { any; };
allow-query-cache { ournets; };

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to a similar problem:

Debian server registered at a Windows Server 2003 was not resolved correctly. sometimes I was able to reach the server through its host name, sometimes not.

the problem was an ipv6 address of the Linux machine. disabling ipv6 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just like to point out one additional possibility, since I just ran into this: someone set the TTL of the DNS record to zero. This actually resolved fine when querying the name server directly, but gave a SERVFAIL when asked trough the local (ubuntu) resolver.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are not using the right queries. You have to ask the root servers for the NS for the TLD (e.g. `dig @ROOT-NS com.`), then ask the TLD bout your domain (e.g. `dig @TLD-NS example.com`) then ask the NS for example.com about www.example.com (e.g. `dig @eaxmple.com-NS-IP www.example.com`)

**Edit:** Here is a full example:

```
dig -t NS .                         # Find the root NS using local resolver
dig -t NS @f.root-servers.net com. 
dig -t NS @a.gtld-servers.net example.com
dig -t A @ns.example.com www.example.com
```

Comment: Hi Mircea.  At the end of the day I'm basically doing the same thing.  Even though I'm asking for a specific host name, rather than NS records, I'm getting a list of authorities and "following the trail", but I get stuck at the query to `example.com-NS-IP`, which either times out or fails with `SERVFAIL`.

Comment: This is incorrect and misleading.  The query resolution process operates by always asking for the information that is actually desired, and following referrals if the answer is not given.  It does _not_ operate by sending `NS` queries until it somehow magically _knows_ when not to.  The attempt to manually replicate the query resolution process (albeit that it didn't follow anywhere near all of the paths) was correct as it stood.